# Android Phonegap screen rotation lock kills my app

Tags: android, cordova, screen-orientation

i'm having problems with my application, i added an manifest that must prevent screen rotation but when i rotate the screen it kills the app.

Here is my code:

```
public class avantdroidActivity extends DroidGap {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    super.clearCache();        
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/redir.html");      
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
}
```

My AndroidManifest.Xml:

```
<activity android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|keyboardHidden"> <intent-filter> </intent-filter> </activity>
```

What im doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you calling?

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

You can just set your activity orientation in your AndroidManifest. 
Just add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to your `activity` tag.

Comment: Still not working look:
04-04 15:22:41.984: D/CordovaLog(229): : Line 0 : exception firing pause event from native
04-04 15:22:42.203: W/webcore(229): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
04-04 15:22:42.303: D/CordovaLog(229): : Line 0 : exception firing destroy event from native
04-04 15:22:42.394: I/ARMAssembler(63): generated scanline__00000077:03010104_00000004_00000000 [ 22 ipp] (41 ins) at [0x310de0:0x310e84] in 6138979 ns
04-04 15:22:42.415: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(229): Ignore this event
04-04 15:22:42.714: D/CordovaLog(229): : Line 0 : exception firing pause event from native

Comment: I start the app with landscape mode, it puts as Portrait, but still crashing when i rotate the screen!

Comment: It works now i forgot to add android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" inside my main activity! i put the same on droidgap activity. now works thanks so much!